# Lyx 2.3 roadmap

Tags: biblatex, lyx, update

I will soon have to write a scientific article. I was planning to do this using Lyx at first and then maybe do the final polishing with a Latex editor. I read in the Lyx page that the new release, 2.3, will have native Biblatex support.

Since I came to really appreciate the potential of Biblatex with a standard Latex editor I was wondering if anyone knows when the 2.3 version will be released or what is the roadmap.

Comment: You may have more luck asking this question either on a LyX mailing list or other support forums: https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists. http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=30758 indicates that a release candidate dates back to end of December last year.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with LyX, but I'm not sure how easy it will be to do the final polishing to a document written in LyX. It seems to me that WYSWIG editors often have the tendency to write more verbose code.

Comment: @moewe it is not so bad, I sometimes get them. The main problem is that one often find "remains" from some formatting like empty `\textbf{ }` and that lyx (or the users ;-)) seems not be able to decide how to write quotes, I saw in a document every possible variant from \glqq to "` to \textquotedbl etc.

Answer (score 3):

We are expecting to announce the second release candidate (rc) for 2.3.0 soon (hopefully within the next few days). I think there's a good chance it will be the last release candidate and that we won't need a third release candidate. However, I cannot say when the final release will be. That will depend on how testing of rc2 goes and what types of bugs are revealed.

To be clear, the final release of 2.3.0 will be different from 2.3.0rc2 so I do not recommend depending on 2.3.0rc2 for serious work.